# $|G| > 1$ and not prime implies existence of a subgroup other than two trivial subgroups

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

My attempt:

Let's divide into two cases:

1) $G$ is cyclic. So, there exists $g$ (not equal to identity element) belonging to $G$, such that $\langle g\rangle = G$. Let, $|G| = m = ab$ ($m$ is non-prime and not equal to $1$) and $a, b$ are not equal to $1$.

Let's look at subgroup $\langle g^a\rangle = \{e, g^a, g^2a,\ldots, g^ba = e\}$ hence, there are $b$ elements in the subgroup, but since $ab = n$, $b < n$. Done.

2) $G$ is not cyclic. So $\langle g\rangle \neq G$. So, $o(g) < |G|$. By definition, the subgroup, $\langle g\rangle = \{e, g, g^2, \ldots, g^{o(g)-1}\}$, but since $o(g) < G$, we are done.

Confusion:

i) In number 2, how can I be sure that the subgroup that I wrote down is indeed correct? Is there any better way to do part 2?
ii) Is the approach in number 1 good?

Comment: In 1), the 'a' is raised as an index. I think you made a mistake while editing the question @Jose

Answer (score 1):

The first part is fine.

The second part is not written clearly. When you wrote “So is not equal to G”, you should have written “So, given $g\in G\setminus\{e\}$, $G\neq\langle g\rangle$”. Then, you could said that $\langle g\rangle$ is the subgroup that you're looking for.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, so does every element g in G, form a subgroup?

Comment: @Patrick No. The only $g\in G$ such that $\{g\}$ is a subgroup is the identity element.

Comment: Maybe i am missing out on a crucial point here, but how does “So, given g∈G∖{e} g∈G∖{e}, G≠⟨g⟩” ensure that such subgroup even exist?

Comment: @Patrick the notation $<g>$ refers to the subgroup generated by $g$ i.e. the elements ${g, g^{2}, ...,g^{n}}$ where $n$ is the order of $g$. Provided that $g\neq e$ this subgroup is not trivial. Also since we are proving the case where $G$ is not cyclic, it must have at least 2 generators meaning our set ${g, g^{2}, ...,g^{n}}$ is a proper subgroup of $G$.

Comment: @pilgrim I am confused on why such subgroup should even exist in the first place. Am I missing out on something?

Comment: @Patrick these subgroups will always exist provided that $G$ is finite.

Comment: @Patrick But you mentioned $\langle g\rangle$ yourself in the original question.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos what I meant to say in the question was: If any such <g> exists, then..... but how can I be sure that it exists in the first place?

Comment: @Patrick *By definition* $\langle g\rangle$ is the smallest subgroup of $G$ containing $g$. Since there is at least one such subgroup ($G$ itself) and since the intersection of subgroups is again a subgroup, $\langle g\rangle$ exists. Since $o(g)<+\infty$,$$\langle g\rangle=\{e,g,g^2,\ldots,g^{o(g)-1}\}.$$